# Is it possible to insert a view of a component into an article or into the template without using plugins or iframes?

Tags: php, component, view

Is it possible to display a view of a component without iframe and plugin?
(That is to say, if possible with a few lines of PHP and maybe SQL queries?)

To be more clear: I'd like to do it directly in the PHP-Template!
(Would be fine to do it in an article as well, as I have written a
PHP-function `showArticle(mixed $ident)`)

(I'm using Joomla 3.5)

I'd like to do something like

```
<jdoc:include type="component" view="example" name="position-x" />
```

or

```
<?php
    show_component('component-name', 'view-name');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check an extension called "[Components Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/components-anywhere)" by Regular Labs. It works by adding the following text werever you want to load your component:

```
{component url/of/the/component}
```

And no, there's no out of box solution.